# INSTALL_NON_MARKET_APPS alternative?

Tags: android

I need to check if the option "Install apps from unknown sources" is enabled or disabled. However, `INSTALL_NON_MARKET_APPS` was deprecated in API 17. Is there a new alternative to check this? This is the old way of checking:

```
boolean canInstallFromOtherSources = Settings.Secure.getInt(Settings.Secure.INSTALL_NON_MARKET_APPS) == 1;
```

**Edit:**

```
    boolean unknownSource = false;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 17) {
        unknownSource = Settings.Secure.getInt(null, Settings.Secure.INSTALL_NON_MARKET_APPS, 0) == 1;
    } else {
        unknownSource = Settings.Global.getInt(null, Settings.Global.INSTALL_NON_MARKET_APPS, 0) == 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [the documentation for `Settings.Secure.INSTALL_NON_MARKET_APPS` points out](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#INSTALL_NON_MARKET_APPS), the replacement is [`Settings.Global.INSTALL_NON_MARKET_APPS`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Global.html#INSTALL_NON_MARKET_APPS).

Comment: Okay, so if I want to make this compatible for all API versions, do I need to include the deprecated version and the replacement? And execute the appropriate one after checking the API on the device or will the replacement support all the previous API's?

Comment: @Extremis: The replacement does not exist on API Level 16 and below. Use `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` to see what version of Android you are running on, and choose which test to run that way.

Comment: How can I use the replacement to retrieve a boolean?

Comment: @Extremis: Basically the same was as the older version, replacing both `Secure` occurrences with `Global`.

Comment: I tried `boolean unknownSource = Settings.Global.getInt(null, Settings.Global.INSTALL_NON_MARKET_APPS) == 1;` but I get error: `07-21 21:28:49.829: E/AndroidRuntime(663): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.provider.Settings$Global`

Comment: @Extremis: Your build target must be API Level 17+. Your `android:minSdkVersion` and `android:targetSdkVersion` can be whatever you want, but you need to compile against API Level 17+ to get API Level 17+ classes and methods.

Comment: I checked the Build target, it is set to 4.2.2 (17) already. What's the problem.

Comment: @Extremis: Sorry, wasn't paying attention -- you're crashing at runtime. That means that either you are trying this on Android 1.x (in which case things get complicated), or perhaps your `if` check of the build is inverted.

Comment: I am now getting a NullPointerException. Is this correct? See EDIT in the top Post.

Comment: @Extremis: You can't pass in `null`. You need to pass in a `ContentResolver`. You get one by calling `getContentResolver()` on some `Context`, such as an `Activity` or `Service`.

Answer (score 2):

[Settings.Secure.INSTALL_NON_MARKET_APPS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#INSTALL_NON_MARKET_APPS) is deprecated in API 17 thus if you have minimalSDK set lower than 17, it is not directly reachable and reflection has to be used.

My solution:

```
public class BackwardCompatibility {    
    private static Class<?> settingsGlobal;

    /**
     * Returns Settings.Global class for reflective calls.
     * Global is a nested class of the Settings, has to be done in a special way.
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public static Class<?> getSettingsGlobal(){
        if (settingsGlobal!=null){
            return settingsGlobal;
        }

        try {
            Class<?> master = Class.forName("android.provider.Settings");
            Class<?>[] classes = master.getClasses();
            for(Class<?> cls : classes){
                if (cls==null) {
                    continue;
                }

                if ("android.provider.Settings$Global".equals(cls.getName())){
                    settingsGlobal = cls;
                    return settingsGlobal;
                }
            }

            return null;
        } catch(Exception ex){
            Log.e(TAG, "Reflective call not successfull", ex);
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Determines whether installing Android apks from unknown sources is allowed.
     * 
     * @param ctxt
     * @return
     */
    public static boolean isUnknownSourceInstallAllowed(Context ctxt){
        try {
            boolean unknownSource = false;
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 17) {
                unknownSource = Settings.Secure.getInt(ctxt.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.INSTALL_NON_MARKET_APPS, 0) == 1;
            } else {
                // Has to use reflection since API 17 is not directly reachable.
                // Original call would be:
                //   unknownSource = Settings.Global.getInt(ctxt.getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.INSTALL_NON_MARKET_APPS, 0) == 1;
                //
                Class<?> c = getSettingsGlobal();
                Method m   = c.getMethod("getInt", new Class[] { ContentResolver.class, String.class, int.class });

                // Obtain constant value
                Field f = c.getField("INSTALL_NON_MARKET_APPS");
                final String constVal = (String) f.get(null);

                unknownSource = Integer.valueOf(1).equals((Integer) m.invoke(null, ctxt.getContentResolver(), constVal, 0));
            }

            return unknownSource;
        } catch(Exception e){
            // Handle this as you like.
            Log.w(TAG, "Cannot determine if installing from unknown sources is allowed", e);
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```