# INSTALL_NON_MARKET_APPS is deprecated as of API 21, what is alternative?

Tags: android, settings, android-settings

I need to check for option INSTALL_NON_MARKET_APPS on API 23 and API 24. So what is alternative for those APIs?

Currenty using this

```
boolean isNonPlayAppAllowed = false;
            try {
                isNonPlayAppAllowed = Settings.Global.getInt(null, Settings.Global.INSTALL_NON_MARKET_APPS, 0) == 1;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

**Edited after Karan Mer answer:**

Using canRequestPackageInstalls() I am getting this message "Call requires API level 26", I need for API 23 and API 24.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17775535/install-non-market-apps-alternative/17775565

Comment: Possible duplicate of [INSTALL\_NON\_MARKET\_APPS alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17775535/install-non-market-apps-alternative)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `canRequestPackageInstalls ()` from `PackageManager`  instead of `INSTALL_NON_MARKET_APPS` as mentioned in the docs [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#canRequestPackageInstalls())

> public abstract boolean canRequestPackageInstalls ()
>
> Checks whether the calling package is allowed to request package
>   installs through package installer. Apps are encouraged to call this
>   API before launching the package installer via intent
>   Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE. Starting from Android O, the user can
>   explicitly choose what external sources they trust to install apps on
>   the device. If this API returns false, the install request will be
>   blocked by the package installer and a dialog will be shown to the
>   user with an option to launch settings to change their preference. An
>   application must target Android O or higher and declare permission
>   Manifest.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES in order to use this API.

Comment: Using canRequestPackageInstalls() I am getting this message "Call requires API level 26", I need for API 23 and API 24.

Comment: from api 21 to 24 you can use `Settings.Secure.INSTALL_NON_MARKET_APPS` looks like it was undeprecated and deprecated back in 24.